# Getting sum of multiple fields in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

how to calculate {SUM} of multiple columns into a one column in In my Crystal reports.

> Total=(VAT+TAX)

Comment: How does your report look like? Where do you want to calculate?

Comment: Unfortunately i cant upload an image as don't have enough reputation yet. As i have mentioned above i want to calculate the sum of five fields at the bottom of the report. if it possible just give me an general expression to calculate the sum in more than one filed within Crystal report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok this how in general it works:

Place your data in detail section and take simmary in report footer, You can take that by right click ojn field and use insert summary option.

Now create a formula `@Total`

```
sum(Vat)+sum(tax)+sum(duty)  //you can select the summary fields from report fields
```

Place the formula in report footer